# String input in .bat script for ffmpeg encoder

Tags: batch-file, ffmpeg

Okay, I have this script which does batch encoding in ffmpeg. It basically calls upon ffmpeg for every file. What I want to do is to make the script ask for input and output locations before it starts executing.

Here is the original script:

```
for %%a in ("*.mp4") do "G:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg" -i "%%a" -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 20 -maxrate 15000k -bufsize 2000k -acodec copy "newfiles\%%~na.mp4"
```

Now I'd like to be able to input a string with a location for the files in he first brackets ("*.mp4") and at the end for "newfiles\%%~na.mp4".

I would presume that %%~na is used to generate number orders or something but I'm not completely sure.

I would presume that two variables/strings need to be created and then utilized by reading from keyboard. Sadly I have absolutely no experience with this. Did some c++ in school but that was that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can query the user for folder name and add it in front like this:

```
@echo off
set /p fromfolder="Enter search folder: "
set /p tofolder="Enter destination folder: "
for %%a in ("%fromfolder%\*.mp4") do "G:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg" -i "%%a" -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 20 -maxrate 15000k -bufsize 2000k -acodec copy "%tofolder%\%%~na.mp4"
```

The `%~nI` (where `I` is variable, which is `a` in your case) will give do this: `expands %I to a file name only` (effectively removing the filename extension from the filename part of the path). When using in .BAT files you need to use `%%` instead of `%`.

If you type `for /?` you will get help for the for-command. It will explain how to use the command, and how to use variable substitutions. Part of `for /?` included here for easy reference:

```
In addition, substitution of FOR variable references has been enhanced.
You can now use the following optional syntax:

    %~I         - expands %I removing any surrounding quotes (")
    %~fI        - expands %I to a fully qualified path name
    %~dI        - expands %I to a drive letter only
    %~pI        - expands %I to a path only
    %~nI        - expands %I to a file name only
    %~xI        - expands %I to a file extension only
    %~sI        - expanded path contains short names only
    %~aI        - expands %I to file attributes of file
    %~tI        - expands %I to date/time of file
    %~zI        - expands %I to size of file
    %~$PATH:I   - searches the directories listed in the PATH
                   environment variable and expands %I to the
                   fully qualified name of the first one found.
                   If the environment variable name is not
                   defined or the file is not found by the
                   search, then this modifier expands to the
                   empty string

The modifiers can be combined to get compound results:

    %~dpI       - expands %I to a drive letter and path only
    %~nxI       - expands %I to a file name and extension only
    %~fsI       - expands %I to a full path name with short names only
    %~dp$PATH:I - searches the directories listed in the PATH
                   environment variable for %I and expands to the
                   drive letter and path of the first one found.
    %~ftzaI     - expands %I to a DIR like output line

In the above examples %I and PATH can be replaced by other valid
values.  The %~ syntax is terminated by a valid FOR variable name.
Picking upper case variable names like %I makes it more readable and
avoids confusion with the modifiers, which are not case sensitive.
```

I would like to point out that normally command line commands takes parameters instead of querying user for input. You can combine this with asking user for input.

```
@echo off
set fromfolder=%1
set tofolder=%2

REM Remove "" from folder names
set fromfolder=%fromfolder:"=%
set tofolder=%tofolder:"=%

REM Ask user if cmd line parameters not provided
IF [%fromfolder%] == [] set /p fromfolder="Enter source folder: "
IF [%tofolder%] == [] set /p tofolder="Enter destination folder: "

echo Source folder: %fromfolder%
echo Destination folder: %tofolder%

REM Execute command
for %%a in ("%fromfolder%\*.mp4") do "G:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg" -i "%%a" -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 20 -maxrate 15000k -bufsize 2000k -acodec copy "%tofolder%\%%~na.mp4"

REM Unset
set fromfolder=
set tofolder=
```

Execute as: `script.bat "folder1" "folder2"`
The "" around the folder names are only required in cases where they contain spaces.